# expected { but found constant

Tags: solidity, function, constant

My code is:

```js
function equity_in_Hadcoins(address investor) external constant returns (uint) {
    return equity_Hadcoins[investor];
} 
// getting the equity in USD of an investor
function equity_in_usd(address investor) external constant returns (uint) {
    return equity_usd[investor];
} 
//buying Hadcoins
function buy_Hadcoins(address investor, uint usd_invested) external  can_buy_Hadcoins(usd_invested) {
    uint  Hadcoins_bought = usd_invested * usd_to_Hadcoins;
    equity_Hadcoins[investor] += Hadcoins_bought;
    equity_usd[investor] = equity_Hadcoins[investor] / 1000;
    total_Hadcoins_bought ;
}
```

I am getting an error:

> expected { but found constant

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Danny! Welcomd to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please, add more details about your issue. For example which line causes the problem? what solidity version are you using? Also include a minimal reproducible example. As it is it fails to compile because several definitions are missing. Sometimes the error isn't in the line that fails but in a previous line or function.

Answer (score 1):

`constant` keyword can't be used to decorate functions, remove them while defining those functions.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Solidity you need to use on functions either the `view` keyword to indicate that the function will only read from the state of the contract, or `pure` to indicate that the function will not read and will not modify the storage.

Your code is refactored as below:

```js
    function equity_in_Hadcoins(address investor) external view returns (uint) {
        return equity_Hadcoins[investor];
    } 
    // getting the equity in USD of an investor
    function equity_in_usd(address investor) external view returns (uint) {
        return equity_usd[investor];
    } 
    //buying Hadcoins
    function buy_Hadcoins(address investor, uint usd_invested) external  can_buy_Hadcoins(usd_invested) {
        uint  Hadcoins_bought = usd_invested * usd_to_Hadcoins;
        equity_Hadcoins[investor] += Hadcoins_bought;
        equity_usd[investor] = equity_Hadcoins[investor] / 1000;
        total_Hadcoins_bought ;
    }
```

Check `view` keyword docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/contracts.html?highlight=pure#view-functions

Check `pure` keyword docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/contracts.html?highlight=pure#pure-functions